# How to make a function triggered with a series of events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a general question from a newbie -

In javascript / (preferably) jQuery, how do I make a function that is triggered if (and only if) multiple events are satisfied?

More specifically, how to I trigger an event only after a **(1.)** button is clicked and **(2.)** an HTML  tag is changed? (Documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: see jquery triggers http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Sounds like a job for _Logical AND `&&`_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: the change event is for inputs, what kind of change are you trying to listen to?

Comment: look into promise objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use promises:

```
$.when(
    $.Deferred(
        function(d) {
            $("#mybutton").click( 
                function() {d.resolve();}
            );
        }),
    $.Deferred(
        function(d) {
            $("#myhtml").change( 
                function() {d.resolve();}
            );
        })
).done( function() { alert("Both click and change happened"); } );
```

Although this will work only the first time.

Comment: It'd also be relatively simple to put that whole thing in a function and start it over in the `done` callback or something.

Comment: Let me see if this works...

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this

```js
function (a, b, fn) {  
    $(a).click(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-state','clicked');
    })       

    $(b).click(function(){
        if ($(a).attr('data-state') == 'clicked') {
            fn(this);
            $(a).attr('data-state','reset');
        }
    })
}
```